# How would I go about running dual monitors using integrated graphics only? (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: drivers, graphics

I've been trying to get dual monitors set up using integrated graphics (don't have a dedicated graphics) on my new build in Ubuntu 20.04, but I'm having issues getting the i915 graphics driver loaded onto the system. I know by default the intel drivers are installed, but whenever viewing my system information it shows that fbdev is loaded and the graphics being used is llvmpipe. Below is a list of things I've already tried with no luck:

Modifying grub file

- Replacing quiet splash with empty string, adding i915.modeset=1, blacklisting nouveau, removing splash, etc.

Adding intel config file under /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d

- Config file contained a section specifying i915 as the matching driver and intel as the device id and driver

Uninstalling all xserver-xorg-video packages other than intel / updating xserver-xorg-video-intel to latest version

Updating Kernel to latest version

inxi -G

Graphics:  Device-1: Intel RocketLake-S GT1 [UHD Graphics 750] driver: N/A
Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: fbdev unloaded: modesetting,vesa
resolution: 1920x1080~77Hz
OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0 256 bits)
v: 4.5 Mesa 21.2.0-devel (git-be4d17c 2021-04-27 hirsute-oibaf-ppa)

uname -r

5.11.0-16-generic

lspci -k -nn -d 8086:

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation RocketLake-S GT1
[UHD Graphics 750] [8086:4c8a] (rev 04)
DeviceName: Onboard - Video
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8694]
Kernel modules: i915

Any ideas on what the issue could be?

Comment: Basically you need proper support for that CPU/GPU and then it'll work.

Comment: @ChanganAuto How would go about getting proper support? I have an i7 11700k CPU

Comment: Wait for the proper support to be added to an upcoming kernel. There's nothing else you can do but wait.